# How to make the main camera rotate with the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following script which should make the main camera follow and rotate with the player's movements.

```
public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    float mouseSensitivity;
    public Vector3 cameraOffset;

    public Transform Player;
    public Transform mainCamera;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        cameraOffset = transform.position - Player.transform.position;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Rotate();
    }

    private void Rotate()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        Player.Rotate(Vector3.up, mouseX);

        mainCamera.Rotate(Vector3.up, mouseX); //shows abnormal rotation (hides the player as well)
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Player.position + cameraOffset;
        transform.position = newPosition;
    }
}
```

The camera follows the player, however, but it does not rotate with the player's rotations. Please note that making the main camera the child of the player is not an option here, since I have to use this script on multiplayer. I want the mouse to be able to rotate both the main camera and the player at the same time.

Comment: Check out [Rotate Around](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)

Comment: Does https://answers.unity.com/questions/1351843/how-can-i-rotate-the-camera-to-the-player-facing-d.html work for you? But its just for the main Camera. You still have to adjust the code to make it camera rotates based on Mouse Input

Comment: @MHRahman this code helps rotating the camera around with the player, but I am unable to change the camera offset values, specifically the y-component.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the camera is not rotating, is that you capture the initial offset on start, which is expressed in absolute (world space) position. This can be easily fixed using transform.TransformPoint method. What you then need to do is address camera rotation. In the simplest case you can just use 'LookAt' method

```
private void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 newPosition = Player.position + Player.TransformPoint(cameraOffset);
    mainCamera.position = newPosition;
    mainCamera.LookAt(Player.position, Vector3.up);
}
```

I also noticed that you use transform.position (a transform from the object your script is attached to) but then you also use mainCamera transform as a seperate transform, mixing it like that might lead to confusion later. You should either always access the camera via mainCamera reference, or you could always keep the script attached to the camera and use transform reference.

I also noticed that you use one script to do two seperate things, it controls both player rotation and camera position/rotation while following the player. While there is nothing stoping you from doing that, its often a good idea to split it into doing two things each doing one logical thing

Comment: I tried adding the above code, but with this I am unable to see the player now. The camera is rotating around the buildings and camera offset values are completely changed during run time.

Comment: thats a bit odd, I tested it and it worked fine for a camera following a cube. have you tried commenting your Update?

Comment: Yes, nothing has changed by commenting the update function. I am still getting the same view.